# MySQL Workbench, want to find maximum percentage of a column after grouping and its corresponding information in other columns

Tags: sql, syntax, mysql-workbench

So basically, I have two tables, One called CountryLanguage and the other called Country.

[image: Click here to view Image]

I've tried al ot of different things but I can't seem to get an answer to my problem:

Both tables have a Country Code which is used to join the tables and each Country has its name. This is the image for the Country Table:

[image: This is the image for the Country Table]

The CountryLanguage Table has a number of languages in each column, a Country Code and a percentage of people who speak the language:

[image: Image for the COuntryLanguage Table]

What I basically was trying to do (for hours and hours) was list the most common language that is spoken in each country (simply by finding the max percentage of each of the languages that are spoken in that country and then linking that value to the Country Language). The syntax is causing me a lot of problems because I'm relatively new to MySQL.

Any Help would be much appreciated. :D

```
SELECT CL.Percentage, C.Name, CL.Language
From world169.CountryLanguage as CL join 
world169.Country as C ON (CL.CountryCode = C.Code)
```

***EDIT:*** 
Thanks for the reply Jinesh. There's another slight problem (which I was having before). I'll show you a before and after picture of what happens when I run the code: [Before:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T79jl.png) It shows the percentage for each language spoken, so When you find the max(percentage) you would expect to get 76.7 and the Language English, right? But instead you [image: (Image ***after*** I run your code)] get the (correct) percentage and the wrong language spoken (This has been another problem I've encountered time and time again.)

How do I get English to be listed out instead of Dutch? (BTW thank you for the help, it's been really useful)

Comment: You can try to use Max() function with Group By clause. Something like `SELECT MAX(CL.Percentage), C.Name, CL.Language
From world169.CountryLanguage as CL join 
world169.Country as C ON CL.CountryCode = C.Code Group By (CL.CountryCode) `

Comment: Thank you SO much for the reply JINESH, I'm having a slight problem though. If you care to read it, it's in the EDIT part above

Comment: You really should use the SQL text instead of big screenshots, which contain a lot of unrelated stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Can we try something like this:

```
SELECT 
  CL.Percentage,
  (Select C.Name from world169.Country as C where CL.CountryCode = C.Code),
  CL.Language
FROM world169.CountryLanguage as CL
WHERE BALANCE = (SELECT MAX(CL2.Percentage) FROM world169.CountryLanguage as CL2 WHERE CL2.CountryCode = CL.CountryCode )
```